# Laravel SMTP Gmail failed

Tags: laravel, smtp, gmail, email

```
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "user@email.com" using 3 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 70sm7122401qkk.10 - gsmtp
 ". Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 70sm7122401qkk.10 - gsmtp
 ". Authenticator XOAUTH2 returned Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 70sm7122401qkk.10 - gsmtp
 ".
```

Good morning, I'm trying to connect Gmail Smtp, above is the error that I get in laravel 5.8, I generated the application password on my personal mail, then sending emails worked, but as when I generated the application password on work mail, I immediately get the error. That is, when I use my personal mail with the application password, then everything is OK, but as soon as I use work mail I immediately get an error.

On both mailboxes I did the following actions, which are described in Google support
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833
https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=user@email.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=generatedAppPassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

So if you can help me do this, I would really appreciate

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you account has  “Access for less secure apps” enabled and that 2fa login is not enabled.

## Update 2022

after the removal of [less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en). You can no longer connect to googles smtp server using the actual password of the users gmail account.

You have two options.

1. enable 2fa on the google account and create an [apps password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833). The apps password can then be used in place of the password in your code.
2. Switch to using [Xoauth2](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol).

[Quick fix for SMTP username and password not accepted error](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_u5KIeXiVI)

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue i resolve this use under

go to gmail.com

my account

and enable

Allow less secure apps: ON

it start works